# "Other" as a pronoun for uncountable nouns

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, determiners

I understand that using "other" as a determiner before an uncountable noun is correct, but I was wondering if it could also be used as a pronoun:

> Is there other accommodation available?
>
> Yes, there is **other**, don't worry

While I understand there are some other determiners that can be used instead, I am really intrigued about this one. Also, please let me know how natural you feel it is in daily speech.

Comment: That doesn't look like native-speaker use to me.

Comment: Not for a mass noun; _another_ can be used for a count noun, but essentially that's a noun phrase, not a pronoun.

Comment: "Is there other accommodation available?" sounds bad. I would say "**Are** there other accommodation**s** available?"

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer: Generally not

Long answer, I could see it being used in an informal setting after "other" has been introduced elsewhere. Almost anything can be used as a pronoun in that sense. For example,

> "Oh, and my sister will be bringing one other with her."
>
> "Okay. Is Other bringing his own drink?"

If no other pronoun has been specified, it's possible to use a determiner as a placeholder. However, in more formal communication, you would not expect to see it.

Comment: That's essentially a noun usage. You even capitalise.

Comment: Yes and even as a capitalized noun, would you really not expect to use "Is the/that Other bringing his own drink" or "Is her Other bringing a towel" or "Is 'Other' eating with us"? Any of them rather than simply "Is Other…"